# RabbitMQ - How to achieve FIFO in priority queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, priority-queue, messagebroker

Below code to add message to priority queue

```
        var priorityArgs = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        priorityArgs.Add("x-max-priority", 10);

        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                             durable: false,
                             exclusive: false,
                             autoDelete: false,
                             arguments: priorityArgs);

 var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
 properties.Priority = Convert.ToByte(10);

 channel.BasicPublish(exchange: string.Empty,
                                 routingKey: "hello",
                                 basicProperties: properties,
                                 body: body);
```

Below code to add message to priority queue without any priority

```
 properties.Priority = Convert.ToByte(0);

                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: string.Empty,
                                 routingKey: "hello",
                                 basicProperties: properties,
                                 body: body);
```

The message added with high priority doesn't obey FIFO which is expected.

But even the message added with '0' priority doesn't obey FIFO which is not as per my use case expectation.

**Question:**  In RabbitMQ priority queues, how to achieve FIFO for those messages which are send without any priority?

Comment: Make the priority a combination of the provided priority plus the time/order of insertion when priorities are equal.

Comment: @pjs how to make priority a combination of the provided priority plus the time/order of insertion?